# React component is not displaying the same way when used multiple times in the same page

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a component created using Tailwind CSS which is rendering one section of a page. `<Section {...props} />`.
This component is an image and a description that includes the number of the section[image: screenshot]

I used this component 4 times in my page, but the problem is that it's not displaying consistently in each instance. It is only displaying properly the first time it's used, as shown in the screenshot.

```
    import LandingStep1 from "../../../assets/images/Landing-step-1.png";
    import LandingStep2 from "../../../assets/images/Landing-step-2.png";
    import LandingStep3 from "../../../assets/images/Landing-step-3.png";
    import LandingStep4 from "../../../assets/images/Landing-step-4.png";
    import landing_1_svg from "../../../assets/images/Landing1.svg";
    import landing_2_svg from "../../../assets/images/Landing2.svg";
    import landing_3_svg from "../../../assets/images/Landing3.svg";
    import landing_4_svg from "../../../assets/images/Landing4.svg";
    import ProcessedButton from "./ProcessedButton";

    const Section = ({ reverse = false, num, title, paragraph, svg, img }) => {
      return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-24">
          <div
            className={`flex justify-between items-center gap-x-20 ${
              reverse ? "flex-row-reverse" : "flex-row"
            }`}
          >
            <div className="flex-1 flex-col">
              <div dir="rtl" className="flex gap-x-3 items-baseline">
                <span className="lg:text-7xl text-4xl font-bold text-[#C111A0]">
                  {num}
                </span>
                <span className="lg:text-3xl text-2xl text-[#63606B] font-bold">
                  {title}
                </span>
              </div>
              <p
                dir="rtl"
                className="lg:text-2xl text-xl font-thin text-[#63606B] mt-10"
              >
                {paragraph}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1 flex justify-center items-center">
              {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/alt-text */}
              <img className="max-w-sm flex-shrink  " src={svg} />
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/alt-text */}
          <img
            className="border-2 border-black rounded-lg w-auto max-w-3xl max-auto"
            src={img}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };

    const LandingDesc = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="p-3 lg:p-20 mx-auto">
            {/* Heading */}
            <div className="w-full mb-32 mt-9 lg:mt-0">
              <h1 className="whitespace-nowrap text-center text-3xl md:text-5xl lg:text-[64px] text-[#63606B] font-bold ">
                مراحل استفاده از اپلیکیشن
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Section
                num={1}
                title="پاسخ به سوالات"
                paragraph="ابتدا سوالات روانشناسی را پاسخ دهید. بر اساس پاسخ شما آرسون بهترین پیشنهاد سرمایه گذاری را ارائه میکند."
                svg={landing_1_svg}
                img={LandingStep1}
              />

              <Section
                num={2}
                title="مشاهده درجه ریسک پذیری"
                paragraph="بر اساس پاسخی که به سوالات داده اید، درحه ریسک پذیری شما مشخص میشود. با دانستن درجه ریسک پذیری سرمایه گذاری مطمئن تری خواهید داشت."
                svg={landing_2_svg}
                img={LandingStep2}
                reverse
              />

              <Section
                num={3}
                title="احظار هویت"
                paragraph="در این مرحله احراز هویت و تکمیل اطلاعات را انجام دهید."
                svg={landing_3_svg}
                img={LandingStep3}
              />

              <Section
                num={4}
                title="مشاهده پیشنهاد سرمایه گذاری"
                paragraph="بسته های سرمایه گزاری منطبق بر ریسک پذیری و سرمایه خود را مشاهده کنید."
                svg={landing_4_svg}
                img={LandingStep4}
                reverse
              />
            </div>

            <ProcessedButton />
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default LandingDesc;
```

Comment: Can you also share an image for when it's not rendering right ?

Comment: @noiseymur
the shared image is when it's not working right. If you look, you can see the size of the images is not same and many other responsive problem will occur when you decrease the size of the window

Comment: Thanks. You need to enclose the image inside a div and manually limit the size of that div, and hence image inside it. Also, consider using media queries for when you decrease the size of screen to get more responsive look.

Comment: @noiseymur thank you for your comment. But unfortunately it didn't work out too. The other pages are working without issue. I guess I will rebuild this page again.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow realized how to fix this issue. Well, since I'm using Figma, I'm copying SVGs, and then I will paste them into an SVG file. So I remembered that SVGs have width and high, and I deleted them in its file (as shown in the below). Now it's working right.

- before :

```
<svg width="708" height="708" viewBox="0 0 708 708" fill="none">
...
..
.
```

- after :

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 708 708" fill="none">
...
..
.
```